# Como ler uma string dentro de um array?

Tags: array, bash

Gostaria de ler um campo do tipo varchar em um banco de dados MySql, que contem varias datas no seguinte formato:

```
"20171012 20171102 20171115 20171120 20171225"
```

todas pra dentro de uma array do tipo, como este abaixo:

```
Data[1]="20171012"

Data[2]="20171102"

Data[3]="20171115"

Data[4]="20171120"

Data[5]="20171225"
```

Como poderia fazer isso? Se puderem me ajudar, agradeço muito.

Comment: Vc quer extrair as dadas da string? Seria [isso](https://ideone.com/qJy9J4) que você precisa?

Comment: A string no banco, contém uma lista de feriados no formato exemplo "20171012 20171102 20171115 20171120 20171225". Dai eu queria extrair cada data dessa e por numa variavel array.

Comment: Coloquei um exemplo no link acima, usa o `explode(' ', $str);` e retorna um array. Veja se resolve o problema.

Comment: Desculpe, verdade, agora que vi o seu Link ... seria bem aquilo mesmo, só que em script bash do Ubuntu.

Comment: Eu que peço desculpa, respondi na tag errada, PHP rsrs

Comment: Marco eu editei a resposta, veja lá.

Comment: opa !! eu vi sua resposta abaixo, e ficou perfeito !!! era isso mesmo !! muito obrigado!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Com base [nesta resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10586169/5429980) eu adaptei um script para você, veja:

```
#!/bin/bash

IFS=' ' read -r -a array <<< "20171012 20171102 20171115 20171120 20171225"

echo "${array[4]}"
```

Saída:

> 20171225

Comment: Isso mesmo!! testei aqui e funcionou de boa !!!

Comment: Muito obrigado!!!

Answer (score 0):

Passo 1 - Crie uma página em PHP que leia a string (Da forma bruta) no banco de dados, salve em um variável (Ex.: `$datas`) e que "retorne" essa string.
Obs.: O "retorno" de que estou falando NÃO é feito com `return $datas`, mas sim com `echo $datas`, pois assim o "retorno" da página pode ser recebido por quem fez a requisição (Nesse caso, o AJAX).

Passo 2 - Crie uma função em Javascript (De preferencia usando Jquery) que faça uma requisição à página em PHP que você criou. Quando você montar a requisição AJAX, terá que passar um função de callback que será responsável por tratar a resposta da requisição (A resposta que o PHP retornará com `echo $datas`).

Passo 3 - Na função de callback que você criou no passo 2, finalmente você terá uma string (Ex.: `datas`) com as datas no formato bruto. Aí você vai usar a função `split` (Que é aplicável a strings) para quebrar a string e salvar o resultado em um vetor. A função `split` separa a string em vários pedaços, de forma que esta separação é controlada pelo parâmetro que você passa ([Saiba mais sobre a split aqui](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp)).

Ex. 1:

```
var datas = "O rato roeu a roupa"
var vetor = datas.split(" "); // Separa o conteúdo de ***datas*** usando ***espaço***
// vetor = {"O", "rato", "roeu", "a", "roupa"}
```

Ex. 2:

```
var datas = "O rato roeu a roupa"
var vetor = datas.split("a"); // Separa o conteúdo de ***datas*** usando ***a***
// vetor = {"O r", "to roeu ", " roupa"}
```

Não sei o teu nível de conhecimento e, das coisas que eu coloquei acima, não sei o você sabe. Portanto, posso ter sido muito prolixo e ter escrito coisas desnecessárias (O que seria bom, por que seria um sinal de que você já sabe) ou posso ter sido muito superficial e não ter explicado muito bem cada coisa. De qualquer forma, se a segunda hipótese for verdade, te aconselho a fazer uma réplica enumerando todos os pontos que você não entendeu e/ou que não sabe como fazer. Assim vai ficar mais fácil da galera te ajudar.

## DoeSangue

## AjudeOPróximo

Comment: Só pra galera não ficar achando que eu tô louco, a categoria inicial da pergunta era WEB (PHP, Jquery, Javascript, etç).
De qualquer forma, fica aí pra quem quiser ver.

Comment: Que nada Alan .. obrigado pelas dicas.. sou novo aqui, e sinceramente.. nem lembro de ter colocado a tag "Web".. certeza que eu tinha colocado MySql, pois os dados eu vou extrair de la.

Comment: De qualquer forma, em um momento laaaaaaa na frente, eu devo usar PHP no bolo ... então, vou guardar essa sua dica :-)